# What is the name of the type of diagram that displays all the forces that act on a moving bicycle so that it stays in balance and does not fall?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bicycles, forces

If I were to draw a diagram the system of forces acting on a bicycle at high speed in order to demonstrate that the bicycle does not fall over, what is tat type of diagram called?
[image]

Comment: If you are a new user, please visit the [tour] page to know more about the kind of information that needs to be added to questions. For example, you can [edit] the question to add the forces that you already know are acting on the system. Also, are *pseudo* forces allowed to be considered or only *real* forces ?

Comment: No.  Research this question yourself and ask questions about things you don't understand.  Start with Cornell University research.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamics problem. So you'd probably need two diagrams, in this type of problem.

You'd need

- the Free Body Diagram which illustrates the forces and moments on the bicycle.
- The Kinetic Diagram which represents the right hand side of the F = ma equation and $M=I\cdot \alpha$

[image]
**Figure: Example of Free body and Kinetic diagram**

IMO, associating each diagram with a side of the Netwon's second law offers a valuable insight. I.e.

- for forces
  $$\begin{align}\sum F &= ma \\
  \text{Free Body Diagram} &= \text{Kinetic Diagram Acceleration}\\
  \end{align}$$
- moments
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum M &= I\cdot \alpha\\
  \text{Free Body Diagram - Moments} &= \text{Kinetic Diag.-  Angular Acceleration}\\
  \end{align}$$

where:

- $a$ is the linear acceleration
- $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration